# Extracting Metadata of E-Mail Attachments: owner/author and last accessed

Tags: java, email-attachments, java-libpst

I am using `java-libpst` to read out the content of pst files. So far, the library is working great. I am able to read the emails and get the attachments,as well as some metadata of the attachments (such as size, etc.)

Additionally, I need to know the owner/author of each attachment and the date it was last accessed. Usually, standard file formats list this information in their properties. However, I have not found a way to extract this information with `libpst`. Has someone done this before and knows a solution?